# python: Dowloading and caching XML files - how to handle encoding declaration?

Tags: python, xml, unicode, encoding, lxml.objectify

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from lxml import objectify
```

I am trying to write a program that will download XML files into a cache and then open them using `objectify`.  If I download the files using `urlopen()` then I can read them in using `objectify.fromstring()` just fine:

```
r = urlopen(my_url)
o = objectify.fromstring(r.read())
```

However, if I download them and write them to a file, I end up with an encoding declaration at the top of the file that `objectify` doesn't like.  To wit:

```
# download the file
my_file = 'foo.xml'
r = urlopen(my_url)

# save locally
with open(my_file, 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(r.read())

# open saved copy
with open(my_file, 'r') as fp:
    o1 = objectify.fromstring(fp.read())
```

results in `ValueError: Unicode strings with encoding declaration are not supported. Please use bytes input or XML fragments without declaration.`

If I use `objectify.parse(fp)` then that works fine- soo-- I could go through and change all the client code to use `parse()` instead, but I feel like that is not the right approach.  I have other XML files stored locally for which `.fromstring()` works just fine-- based on a cursory review they appear to have `utf-8` encoding.

I just don't know what is the right resolution here- should I change the encoding when I save the file? should I strip the encoding declaration? should I fill my code with `try.. except ValueError` clauses? please advise.

Comment: Please try using `open(my_file, 'rb')` because of `Please use bytes input`.

Comment: @simon-kirsten That does work--- this is another one of those things that changed from python2 to python3 isn't it

Comment: Could be, not sure. Glad it works :)

Comment: Just posted an answer to get them rep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file needs to be opened in binary mode rather than text mode.

```
open(my_file, 'rb') # b stands for binary
```

as suggested by the exception: `... Please use bytes input ...`